# Testing with mongoose and typescript: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - node_modules/mongodb/src/bson.ts:38:3

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

I'm running tests with jest on a node/express application. Anytime that I run anything with mongoose I get the following error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run
    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

      at Object.get [as ObjectId] (node_modules/mongodb/src/bson.ts:38:3)
      at Object.get [as ObjectId] (node_modules/mongodb/src/bson.ts:38:3)
      (... line repeats total of 10 times)
```

When I've read other stackoverflow posts on this it tends to be an issue of iterating over multiple documents, but I still get an issue when I'm considering a single document:

```js
test("mongoose works", async () => {
    console.log("this does not log") // Nothing logs and I get the "test suite failed to run" error
    const findResponse = await UserAction.findOne({
      action: "testString1",
    }).exec();
    expect(findResponse).toBe(false);
  });
```

The fact that my console.log doesn't run at all makes me thing there's something wrong with mongoose/typescript. If I remove mongoose from the test it runs fine.

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to have been with my `jest.config.js` file. I had `moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],` set. When I commented this line out I no longer had the problem.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I spent most of the day on this 