# TS-JEST Mongoose/MongoDB incompatibility with ESM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ts-jest, ts-node

I am trying to get Node Express/Typescript app that uses Mongoose (which drags in Mongodb) to work with Jest. I know what the error is, I just can't find the correct configuration to get jest and mongodb to play nicely.

No matter what I try I either get:

```
chart-review-server2.0/node_modules/mongodb/src/bson.ts:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import type {
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

or if I try to exclude it from the config using transformIgnorePatterns in my jest.config.js configuration like this: transformIgnorePatterns: `['node_modules/(?!(mongodb))'],` I get:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

      at Object.get [as ObjectId] (node_modules/mongodb/src/bson.ts:38:3)
      at Object.get [as ObjectId] (node_modules/mongodb/src/bson.ts:38:3)...
```

My jest.config.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transformIgnorePatterns: [`node_modules/(?!(mongodb))`],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  moduleDirectories: [ "node_modules", "src", "test"],
  verbose: true,
  testMatch: ["<rootDir>/test/*(*.)+(test).+(ts)"],
  setupFiles: [
    'dotenv/config'
  ],
};
```

my tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "rootDirs": [
      "./src"
    ],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": true

  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "types": [
    "node"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for any replies, and for reading this.

Comment: The same issue in my project. Can't find any answer related to this

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out `moduleDirectories` on jest.config.js solved the issue for me. All credits to @jimmythecode, see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72288368/7827130).